# trouble proving a trigonometric identity for sum/difference formula of tangent

Tags: trigonometry

My teacher is making the jump from step 1 to the QED of the proof, but from what I understand about the sum/difference formula pertaining to tangent it shouldn't be this simple.

$$\frac{\tan(a) + \tan(b)}{\tan(a) - \tan(b)}$$

somehow becomes

$$\frac{\tan(a+b)}{\tan(a-b)}$$

Am I missing some critical identity here?

Comment: It's not true.${}$

Comment: thats what I thought, but unless this guy is pulling stuff out of a hat he does have a phD in math....

Comment: You should judge mathematicians by the quality of their mathematics, not the list of qualifications they have amassed.

Comment: I know, but thats what surprises me I wouldnt think a phD math guy would make such a dumb error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\tan(a)+\tan(b)}{\tan(a)-\tan(b)}=\frac{\frac{\sin(a)}{\cos(a)} + \frac{\sin(b)}{\cos(b)}}{\frac{\sin(a)}{\cos(a)} - \frac{\sin(b)}{\cos(b)}} = \frac{\frac{\sin(a)\cos(b) + \sin(b)\cos(a)}{\cos(a)\cos(b)}}{\frac{\sin(a)\cos(b) - \sin(b)\cos(a)}{\cos(a)\cos(b)}} = \frac{\frac{\sin(a+b)}{{\cos(a)\cos(b)}}}{\frac{\sin(a-b)}{{\cos(a)\cos(b)}}} = \frac{\sin(a+b)}{\sin(a-b)}$$

this is not equal to $$\frac{\tan(a+b)}{\tan(a-b)}$$

Comment: ok so basically my teacher was wrong. Haha I dont know if that is reassuring or comforting seeing as I thought something was fishy

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\frac{\tan(a)+\tan(b)}{\tan(a)-\tan(b)}=\sin (a+b) \csc (a-b)$$

Comment: are you getting this by multiplying denominator by conjugate?

Comment: ah I see you were combining fractions....